# Android socket bind exception

Tags: android

i am new to Android networking concepts.Now i am trying to connect my server and close the socket.after that i am create a new socket with old ip and port.It causes address already in use exception? can any one help me.below is my following code

```
Socket socket=new Socket("122.165.81.120",10200);
                int port=socket.getLocalPort();
                socket.shutdownInput();
                socket.shutdownOutput();
                try{
                socket.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                Socket socket2=new Socket();
                SocketAddress myaddress = new InetSocketAddress("172.16.1.37",port);
                socket2.bind(myaddress);
                socket2.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [`SO_REUSEADDR`](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml) socket option. This is done with the [`Socket.setReuseAddr`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#setReuseAddress%28boolean%29) function.